# Creating grouped attributes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on a project on angular 9 that enables a user to add products to his/her shop and each product has attributes that are grouped based on the category they fall into. In my template, I have a (change)=$event that gets called whenever an attribute is selected. My challenge is that under a particular category, a product has certain attributes that I'd liked to be group based on their group name. For instance, I have an attribute group under the 'Automotives' category that looks like;

**Safety** (Group name)

- Airbags
- Anti-lock breaking systems
- Child safety system
- etc.

**Human-machine interface (Another group)

- Air-conditioned
- bluetooth
- WiFi
- etc.

From the above groupings, one can select attributes from each group and each selected attribute gets grouped under the given group name. So far my code (My component Class) looks like this:

```
   /**
   * Attempts to create a group of attributes as selected by the user
   * @param string groupname
   * @return void
   */
  createAttributesFor(groupname,$event){
    let value = $event.target.value

    if($event.target.checked)
    {
      if(this.attributesGroup.length)
      {
        for(let k of this.attributesGroup)
        {
          if(k.group == groupname)
          {
            if(!k.options.includes(value))
              k.options.push(value)
          }else
             this.attributesGroup.push({group : groupname, options : [value]})
        }
      }else
        this.attributesGroup.push({group : groupname, options : [value]})
    }
    console.log(this.attributesGroup)
  }
```

This is what I have on my template:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'check'" class="mb-1">
  <div *ngIf="f.options" class="mt-1">
    <label class="control-label mb-0"><small><b>{{ f.name | uppercase}}</b></small></label>
    <div class="col-form-label p-0 mb-0" *ngFor="let o of f.options">
       <div class="form-check">
        <input id="{{ o }}" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ o }}" [formControlName]="f.name" (change)="createAttributesFor(f.name,$event)">
        <label for="{{ o }}" class="control-label mb-0"><small>{{ o | titlecase }}</small></label>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

My problems is;

When I select an attributes for a specific group (say **Safety**), the grouping works as it should but if I move to the next group and subsequent groups, each attribute I select gets grouped into a new group whether or not that group already exists. I cannot figure out why this is happening. I got the screenshot  to create an image of what I am trying to explain:

[image: Image of the attributes and their groups]

[image: A console log of the challenge I am facing]

I need your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are iterating over all the groups and checking if current group is the correct one, so when you get there with 'Bluetooth', first it checks if 'human-machine interface' == 'SAFETY', it doesnt, so it goes to the else, and creates a new entry in the array, then it compares 'human-machine interface' to 'human-machine interface' and adds bluetooth to the existing group.

You need to get the group with filter:

```
if($event.target.checked)
{
  if(this.attributesGroup.length)
  {
    const group = this.attributesGroup.find(g => g.group === groupname);
    if (group) {
      if(!k.options.includes(value))
          k.options.push(value)
    } else {
       this.attributesGroup.push({group : groupname, options : [value]})
    }
  }else
    this.attributesGroup.push({group : groupname, options : [value]})
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you for pointing out my short-comings. I edited your answer to properly show how the filter is used to get the current group.

Comment: ```if($event.target.checked)
    {
      if(this.attributesGroup.length)
      {
        const group = this.attributesGroup.find(g => g.group === groupname);
        if (group) {
          if(!group.options.includes(value))
              group.options.push(value)
        } else {
           this.attributesGroup.push({group : groupname, options : [value]})
        }
      }else
        this.attributesGroup.push({group : groupname, options : [value]})
    } ```